# React useEffect to redirect to other page if not authenticated does not work on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using reactJS. After login, the server sends me an object that contains the following shape:

```
{
  userId: ,,,
  isAuthenticated: true
......
}
```

I am using useEffect to check if the user is authenticated with the help of the isAuthenticated key. if is not, I redirect it to login page. Well, this works in local and production. However, in the browser, even if it works, the browser keep redirect me to login page, even if the login function is a success...

```
const Profile = () => {

  const myUserContext = useContext(userContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myUserContext?.isAuthenticated === false) {
      navigate('/login');
    }
    else {
      navigate('/profile');
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [myUserContext]);



 
  return (
    <main>
      {myUserContext && myUserContext.completedProfile === false && <TopHeader name={myUserContext?.name} />}

      {/* Navigator with profile image */}
      <Actions picture={myUserContext?.picture}/>

        
    </main>
  );
};
```

UPDATE:
The user context is using axios to get the user from backend.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getProductionURL } from '../lib/getProductionURL';

export const userContext = createContext({});
const Context = props => {

    const [userState, setUserState] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(getProductionURL('/api/get-user'), { withCredentials: true })
            .then(res => {
                if (res?.data) {
                    setUserState(res.data);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, []);


  return (
    <userContext.Provider value={userState}>{ props.children }</userContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default Context
```

The user ourput is :

```
{
completedProfile: false
dateCreated: "2023-09-14T12:19:55.933Z"
googleId: "986683439250694"
isAdmin: false
isAuthenticated: true
name: "Daniel Mick"
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information to solve your problem. All we can do is guessing. Is `isAuthenticated` declared? What's the output of `myUserContext` (try to console log it)? My best bet it this is because of first render. At first render your context is not set, so your `useEffect` is redirecting you to to some page. You can try to add at top of `useEffect` smth like `if(!isFirstRender) return` - it might help.

Implementation of first render check: https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-is-first-render

Comment: I added the user context and the user output. The isAuthenticated is coming from the user context object.

Answer (score 2):

As [ulou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4983752/ulou) mentionned under your question, the first render is most probably the cause of the issue.

The reason is getting the user context is async.
On that first render, the `myUserContext` is defined as `Promise<pending>`, which turns into a `false` in a boolean condition.

So if the `myUserContext` is not yet correctly defined, you should simply return on that useEffect and wait until having the good information to navigate correctly.

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!myUserContext){ return }
  navigate(myUserContext.isAuthenticated ? '/profile' : '/login');
}, [myUserContext]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Just discovered that on mobile I do not get any data. I removed all the useEffect and I dont get the required data at all

Comment: For curiosity, which mobile browser are you testing?

Comment: Chrome and safari. On the production level on the laptop browser, I have no problem. But in the context file created above, i dont get the data on mobile browsers

Comment: Look at the dev tools network tab if anything is blocked for some reason. I personnally never used it yet, but something to look at is [Chrome DevTools for mobile](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/devtools-mobile/).